# Data redundancy in M-M relationship

Tags: database

I have a database which contain Many to Many relationship (look at book, copies, branch [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goPl5.png)) but the problem is that there will be data redundancy, how to solve this problem? is there any way to normalize it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your table "fine" you could remove the `member_id (FK)` because you get that by accessing the parameter `loan_id(FK)`, like:

fine_id -> loan_id(fk) -> member_id(fk)

Then, I would also remove `book_id(fk)` and `branch_id (fk)` from `loan` table. Instead of these attributes, you could insert the `copies_id` from `copies` table (create an id for that table first). So, using that id, you know that a copy of the `book_id` has been taken by member_id

So, change these two tables like so:

```
fine (id, loan_id (fk), fine_date, fine_amount)

loan (id, copies_id (fk), member_id (fk), loan_date, return date).
```

This remove a little bit of redundancy.